# Same Role with different actions for different users spring boot security

Tags: spring-security

I am using spring boot security and MySQL db, completed role base permission but need help for  Same Role with different actions for different users

Comment: a little bit more info would be helpful... do you want to restrict actions based on the principal?   [spring-data-security](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-security)

Comment: yes correct, for ex emp1 and emp2 having (employee role)  same role